# console showing ref not defined - condition not satisfied even when it is supposed to be

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the below code is to updae the value in the database only when the condition of function check() is satisfied

when i compile it the console show error like

**output 1.html:274 Uncaught ReferenceError: ref is not defined**

```
function check()
{

var myInput = document.getElementById("user_name2");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");

  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
  myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
  myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
  myInput.onkeyup = function() {
    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
      letter.classList.remove("invalid");
      letter.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      letter.classList.remove("valid");
      letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }



    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
      number.classList.remove("invalid");
      number.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      number.classList.remove("valid");
      number.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate length
    if(myInput.value.length >= 4) {
      length.classList.remove("invalid");
      length.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      length.classList.remove("valid");
      length.classList.add("invalid");
    }
  }


}
```

this is the script file

```
function save_user(){
   var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
   var user_name2 = document.getElementById('user_name2').value;

   uid = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

   var data = {
    user_id: uid,
    user_name: user_name,
    password: user_name2
   }

   var updates = {};
   updates['/users/' + uid] = data;
   if(check())
   {
   firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

   alert('The user is created successfully!');
   reload_page();

   document.writeln(uid);
   }
   else{
     alert('condition not satisfied');
   }


  }
```

the expected output of this code is that the values entered should satisfy atleast 1 number minimum 4 characters and atleast 1 lower case letter

Comment: Since the error is `output 1.html:274 Uncaught ReferenceError: ref is not defined`, what is line `274` of your `output 1.html` file?

Comment: ```function reload_page(){
   window.location.reload();
  }``` the closing butterfly bracket is the line 274

Comment: That line was not in the original code you shared, not is there any use of `ref` in that line. It'll be hard to help without seeing a minimal reproduction of the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and follow the guidance in there to maximize the chances that someone can help.